# rewrite POST method on rest api yii2

Tags: rest, api, yii, yii2, yii2-api

I must rewrite post request on rest yii2.
Every time i've post request on url v1/availability
I want to call actionCreate for manage request.

This is my main.php

```php
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => ['v1/availability'],
                    'pluralize' => true,
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'POST v1/availability' =>   'v1/availability/create'
                    ]
                ],
                'OPTIONS v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
                'POST v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
                'POST v2/user/login' => 'v2/user/login',
                'OPTIONS v2/user/login' => 'v2/user/login',
            ],
        ],
```

In the v1/controllers/AvailabilityController.php
i've

```php
public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['view']);
        return array_merge(
            $actions,
            [
                'index' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
                    'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
                    'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
                    'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'index']
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

public function actionCreate(){
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(200, 'IT WORKS!', 200);
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add url rule outside like below.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => ['v1/availability']
                ],
                'POST v1/availability' =>   'v1/availability/create',
                'OPTIONS v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
                'POST v1/user/login' => 'v1/user/login',
                'POST v2/user/login' => 'v2/user/login',
                'OPTIONS v2/user/login' => 'v2/user/login',
            ],
        ],
```

And here you need understand rules of Yii. if you add one rule like below.

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
```

this open many urls for clients.

```
[
    'PUT,PATCH users/<id>' => 'user/update',
    'DELETE users/<id>' => 'user/delete',
    'GET,HEAD users/<id>' => 'user/view',
    'POST users' => 'user/create',
    'GET,HEAD users' => 'user/index',
    'users/<id>' => 'user/options',
    'users' => 'user/options',
]
```

above all urls will open for clients.

Answer (score 0):

So...
there are 2 way to override post.

First @Irfan Ali method
This method permit to declare single call in main.php and work with single function in controller.

Second method is 
in main.php declare general call to availability

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => ['v1/availability'],
                'pluralize' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

for intercept post method you must override in the controller

```
public function createAction($id){
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(200, 'You receive post or put', 200);
}
```

and in this function you must intercept if call is post you do anything.

I love first method!